# Integration test db h2

Tags: java, integration-testing, h2

Hello i want to make a integration test for my db in h2. But i have some problem with my method.
My integration test code :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class Team_database_integration_test {

    @MockBean
    private TeamRepository teamRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Test
    public void testDb() {
        Team team = new Team(1L, "teamName", "teamDescription", "krakow", 7);
        testEntityManager.persist(team);
        testEntityManager.flush();

        Assert.assertEquals(1L, teamRepository.findById(team.getId()));
    }
}
```

My error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :1
Actual   :Optional.empty
```

I think a reason is in my service method findbyid:

```
public Optional<TeamDto> findTeamById(Long id) {
        Assert.notNull(id, "ID must exist ");
        return teamRepository
                .findById(id)
                .map(p -> modelMapper.map(p, TeamDto.class));
    }
```

Comment: In you test code you use repository directly to select the data. Not the service.

Comment: So my service code does not matter? in service i have method findteambyid but i use findById. But error means Optional.empty

Comment: The structure of your project is quite not clear for me. I assume you have a Service class that injects TeamRepository. And you a trying to mock repository in your code in order to use the in memory db.

The first question is which scenario are you trying to test by the test above?

Also in your assertion you a trying to compare the Long to Optional. It never gonna work.

Comment: In my assertion i try to compare long with long:/

Comment: Optional.empty is not a long :)